# Finding number of times a sport comes up for each country python data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am stuck on a problem about Olympics athletes.
I need to find the number of different sports each country participates in from my data frame, I am unsure how to do this as the column 'country' obviously has duplicates as well as the column 'sport' and I cant figure out how to group them and return a value for each country

Any help would be awesome :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(by=('country', 'sport')).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'Country': 'India', 'Sport': 'Badmintan'}, {'Country': 'China', 'Sport': 'Badmintan'},{'Country': 'India', 'Sport': 'Football'}])

print(df)

print(df.groupby(by=('Country')).count())

Answer:
Country
China        1
India        2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).